# Understanding second conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

> If I had a day off from work next week, I would go to the beach.

What does this mean ?

1). I know that there is **little possibility** for day off next week and imagining  if I have a day off next week

2). I am **sure** that I won’t have a day off next week and just imagining what if I have a day off

If both are correct, what comes first to a native speaker?

Comment: It doesn't mean either of those things—and neither interpretation "comes first." I could say the original sentence whether there was a 5% chance of me having a day off next week or there was a 95% chance of it. Hypotheticals, as statements, have nothing to do with the probability or liklihood of the triggering event occurring. They only describe something being imagined, and the *consequences* that can result if something does happen.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view, "sure" is not supposed to be used for anything in the future - simply because we cannot see (yet?) into the future. Therefore, there is always a small mount of uncertainty.

From this point of view, "little possibility" and "sure" mean the same thing.

---

Note: Your statement number 2 should actually be written as:

> I am **sure that if nothing major changes** I won't have a day off next week...